# Permission denied error while rsync

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, rsync

We have one script to rysnc the files from main server to many servers.

main server : only one host

Many servers : consider 10 hosts

Script shown below

```
!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
   echo "Usage: $0 <server conf> <path conf>"
   exit
fi

myDir=`dirname $0`
serverConf="$myDir/$1"
pathConf="$myDir/$2"
#rsFlags="-e ssh -v --stats --archive --delete -p -t -T /var/tmp"
rsFlags="-e ssh -v --stats --archive --no-g --delete -T /var/tmp"

for server in `/bin/cat $serverConf | grep -v "^#" | egrep -v "^ *$"`
do
   for path in `/bin/cat $pathConf | grep -v "^#" | egrep -v "^ *$"`
   do
      echo "rsync $path to $server at `/bin/date`"
      ssh -q $server "if [ ! -d $path ]; then /bin/mkdir -p $path; fi"
      rsync $rsFlags $path/ $server:$path
   done
done
~
```

While copying the files from main server , ( `Directory : /eqstore/tpettp/netprobe/ )`

the particular file is getting ignored for all the 9 hosts but script is trying to copy this file to the last (10 ) host alone . same script is tried in another 10 group of hosts , but the case is similar (trying to copy below file for last (10) host alone).

File:

```
-rw------- 1 tpettp   ettp 294027264 Apr 19 07:31 core.10179
```

Due to copying this file our autosys job getting failed

```
Error : rsync: send_files failed to open "/eqstore/tpettp/netprobe/core.10179": Permission denied (13)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]
```

How the file is ignored to all the hosts but not to the last host. Also how to solve this permission denied error

Please help on this. If question is not clear , let me know

Comment: Are you sure the loop is running 10 times?  Does it help if you change `ssh -q` to `ssh -nq`?

Comment: I suspect there is a problem with a trailing `'/'` in `$path/ $server:$path`, but it is hard to tell what is in `serverConf="$myDir/$1"` and `serverConf="$myDir/$1"`. Can you show a complete command line?

Comment: [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). There are also a bunch of quoting issues here that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch. And this is *entirely* at risk for shell injection -- if you had a path with `$(somecommand)` in it, that would be run on the remote side.

Comment: (And using `$rsFlags` to contain multiple options is an inflexible approach prone to the issues described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).

Comment: More on the topic of the immediate error -- `Permission denied` is pretty straightforward. Investigating it requires a bunch of information you haven't given in the question -- which user you're connecting to the server as; the ownership and permissions of all parent directories to the destination; etc. Keep in mind that opening `/foo/bar/baz` requires `+x` on `/`, `/foo`, and `/foo/bar`.

Comment: As for the question of what's happening for which hosts, the log from running your script with `bash -x scriptname` would be helpful.

Comment: That's about as good a road-map as I've seen given in 4-comments. `:)`